# Android, achieve a nested view system like a file manager?

Tags: android

In an android file manager I can make as many nested folders as I want, each inside another. Point is that when I close each folder, the previous view is resumed correctly.

Assuming that each folder is an activity, how can I have infinite nested activities on user command (like making a new folder) which are resumed correctly when user presses back button?

I know that I can make infinite activities using a single layout, but they won't resume properly at back button press. Like when I use an adapter for each view which inflates child views (folders) inside the view. In this case, android just resumes the last inflated view for all back button presses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using multiple `Activities` to implement this use case is not an optimal solution, since you'll quickly get out of memory if you have a deeply nested file structure. Instead, when the user navigates into a directory - just load the contents of that directory and populate the UI, same goes for backwards navigation. If you're using a `ListView` (or a `RecyclerView`) to list the files inside a directory, then all you have to do is to pass the files of the newly selected directory to the `Adapter` every time a user navigates back or forward.

Some pseudocode to illustrate the idea:

```
void onListItemClick() {
  File selectedDir = adapter.getSelectedDir();
  File[] selectedDirContents = selectedDir.list();
  adapter.setFiles(selectedDirContents);
}
```

Comment: So practically you mean the best way is to override the activity onResume() and populate the view again even at backward navigation?

Comment: Or maybe onKeyDown() must be overridden?

Comment: You're reusing the same Activity for the entire navigation process, so there will be no onResume().

Comment: I added a short code snippet to make the idea more clear, please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yes. I totally got that! My main question was whether i should populate the views at backward navigation or there is a way which android takes care of it. Well apparently i must take care of backward navigation and populate the views. I guess it can be done by overriding onKeyDown(). Thanks. Helped a lot.

Comment: You can use Activity's onBackPressed().